# Remove function for a BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am working on a basic BST and wanted a bit of help with the remove function. The following is my understanding to achieve removing the node.

**Removing a leaf node** - simply remove the node (with the pointer from its parent) and return its data

**Removing a node with only left child** - simply remove the node and set its parent’s child to the node’s left child

**Removing an internal node** - a substitute node (the smallest from the right sub-tree) must replace the current node, and the substitute’s right child (if present) would take the substitute’s prior position

Is the below correct for implementing the above mentioned logic?

```
// main function to remove node with "data"
template <typename T>
T BSTree<T>::delete(T& data){
    // BSTree is empty
    if (root == NULL){
        return root;
    }
    return delete(root, data);
}

// recursive function to locate the node to be removed and alter the respective pointers
template <typename T>
T BSTree<T>::delete(BTNode<T>* node, T& data){
    // "data" is to the left of sub-tree
    if (node->getData() > data){
        return delete(node->getLeft(), data);
    }
    // "data" is to the right of sub-tree
    else if (node->getData() < data){
        return delete(node->getRight(), data);
    }

    // now, node points to the node with "data"

    // if node is leaf; delete the node and any pointers to it
    if (node->getLeft() == NULL and node->getRight() == NULL){
        // if node is the left child; parents left child will be null
        if (node->getParent()->getData() > data){
            node->getParent()->setLeft(NULL);
        }
        // node is the right child; parents right child will be null
        else{
            node->getParent()->setRight(NULL);
        }
    }
    else{
        // node to be deleted has only the left child
        if (node->getRight() == NULL){
            node->getLeft()->setParent(node->getParent);
            // if node is the left child; parents left child will be nodes left child
            if (node->getParent()->getData() > data){
                node->getParent()->setLeft(node->getLeft());
            }
            // node is the right child; parents right child will be nodes left child
            else{
                node->getParent()->setRight(node->getLeft());
            }
        }
        // node to be deleted has both children
        else{
            BTNode<T>* deleteNode = node;
            // iterate to the smallest from the right sub-tree
            node = node->getRight();
            while(node->getLeft()){
                node = node->getLeft();
            }
            // if the substitute has a right child; put it in the substitutes place
            if (node->getRight()){
                node->getParent()->setLeft(node->getRight());
                node->getLeft()->setParent(node->getParent());
            }
            // replace deleteNode and node (ie substitute node)
            node->setParent(deleteNode->getParent());
            // if deleteNode is the left child; parents left child will be node
            if (deleteNode->getParent()->getData() > data){
                deleteNode->getParent()->setLeft(node);
            }
            // deleteNOde is the right child; parents right child will be node
            else{
                deleteNode->getParent()->setRight(node);    
            }
            node = deleteNode;
        }
    }
    delete node;
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Did you test it on a large enough amount of trees? Any problems?

Comment: Your code might implement the logic you describe but your logic is wrong. You forgot the case where `data` is found nowhere under `root`. Before posting here, you have apparently not tested your code properly because such a scenario would make your application crash, and a short debug session would have clearly shown you the issue. -> Always include in your unit tests cases where the data is out of scope or out of range (e.g. square root of a negative integer; arcsine/arccosine of a number outside [-1, 1]). Obviously, an application must not crash even in these cases.

Comment: BTW, had you provided the entire class definition in the form of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I could have answered you with the corrected + tested code instead of only commenting.